# EF linq query where condition based on bool parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have an EF linq query where I want to set a where condition based on a true/false parameter.  I can do something similar in SQL which is somewhat how I've written my EF query but it doesnt seem to work with EF Core.

When I expect the executed SQL if I pass "activeOnly = true" then no SQL where condition is applied and when I pass "activeOnly = false" then the condition is "where 0 = 1".

Clearly I have this wrong but I cant figure out the right way to do this? Or if its possible?

```
 public async Task<List<UserDto>> GetUsersAsync(string region, bool activeOnly)
    {
        var allUsers = new List<UserDto>();
        var countries = _configuration.GetRegionConfiguration(region).Countries;

        foreach (var country in countries)
        {
            _context.ChangeConnectionString(country.DatabaseConnectionString);
            
            var users = await _context.User
                .ProjectTo<UserDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                .Where(x => (activeOnly && (x.RoleIds != null)) || (!activeOnly && (x.RoleIds == null)))
                .ToListAsync();
            
            allUsers.AddRange(users);
        }

        allUsers.OrderBy(x => x.FullName);
        return allUsers;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Current versions emit a helpful warning when you use this kind of query:

> Collection navigations are only considered null if their parent entity is null. Use 'Any' to check whether collection navigation 'YourEntity.YourNavigationColleciton' is empty.

So instead of

```
x.RoleIds != null
```

use

```
x.RoleIds.Any()
```